# C++ Pointer Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

**Code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

void someFunc(double* pDoubleArray, int length)
{
    double* pNewDoubleArray = new double[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        pNewDoubleArray[i] = i * 3 + 2;
    }

    pDoubleArray = pNewDoubleArray;
}
int main()
{
    double dbls[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int length = sizeof dbls / sizeof dbls[0];

    std::cout << "Before..." << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << dbls[i] << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    someFunc(dbls, length);

    std::cout << "After..." << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << dbls[i] << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    while(true){ }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Before...
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
After...
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

Here's what I am trying to do:
1. Create an array and fill it with some values
2. Pass that array as a pointer to a function that will create a new array and reassign the one that was passed in to the newly created array
3. Print out the changes

I am not seeing any changes though, and I do not know why.

Comment: Sigh. Yet again, std::vector is what you really want.

Comment: But not passing the `vector<double>` by reference will result in the same problem.

Comment: Can you confirm that you actually want to create a new array, rather than modifying the array you already have? Your `main` function seems to want the original array to be modified.

Comment: Yes I do want to create a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface of your function someFunc is wrong. It should require the reference of a pointer's address (or the pointer to a pointer) so that you can return the address of your new array. Otherwise, you are simply modifying a local value.

```
void someFunc(double*& pDoubleArray, int length)
{
  double* pNewDoubleArray = new double[length];

  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    pNewDoubleArray[i] = i * 3 + 2;
  }

  pDoubleArray = pNewDoubleArray;
}
```

Your calling main function should then pass a value which can be modified:

```
int main()
{
  double dbls[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  double* pArray = dbls;
  // ...

  someFunc(pArray, length);
  // ...

  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    std::cout << pArray[i] << ", ";
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Out of curiosity though - how do I pass a pointer to a pointer? I tried: void someFunc(double** pDoubleArray, int length), and then pDoubleArray = (double**)pNewDoubleArray; and someFunc((double**)pArray, length); but this resulted in my original problem of no changes occuring...

Comment: @Storm: you will need to get the address of the variable using the `&` operator: `pArray = &dbls;`. But please have in mind that changing a reference to a newly allocated instance often means that you will lose the reference to your old data. If the old data was also created on the heap (using the `new` keyword), it means that memory will never be reclaimed.

Comment: @Groo: I tried to do: double* pArray = &dbls; and there was an error: cannot convert from 'double (*)[5]' to 'double *'

Comment: @Storm: sorry, I didn't get what line of code you were referring to. I've updated my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982633/c-pointer-arrays/5982805#5982805) below with the example of `double**` as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the memory leak issue that results:

```
void someFunc(double* & pDoubleArray, int length)
// pass by reference ^^^ the pointer
```

Comment: The name of an array can be used as a pointer r-value, but not a pointer l-value.  Your "fix" won't compile.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, are you positive about that?  The accepted answer seems to say otherwise. :-)

Comment: Yes, I'm positive.  The accepted answer changed the actual parameter, it isn't `dbls` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The line     pDoubleArray = pNewDoubleArray; assigns the local copy of the pointer

Either pass the pointer by reference, pass a pointer to it, or return the new value

My preference would be to return the new value, bit that's a style issue.

Comment: You could also just change the values in-place, thus avoiding allocating and leaking a new array, of course

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you are passing the old array to a function which **does not use it**.

If you are changing individual values, then there is no point in creating a new array instance. If not, then simply create a new array and return it.

So, either change the original array:

```
void someFunc(double* pDoubleArray, int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        pDoubleArray[i] = i * 3 + 2;
    }
}
```

Or return the new array from the function:

```
// this indicates that the returned value is
// actually a new instance
double* getNewArray(double* pDoubleArray, int length)
{
    double* pNewDoubleArray = new double[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        pNewDoubleArray[i] = i * 3 + 2;
    }

    return pNewDoubleArray;
}
```

An alternative is to pass the input array by reference, but that complicates releasing unused instances.

**[Edit]**

To clarify this last case:

```
void someFunc(double** pDoubleArray, int length)
{
    double* pNewDoubleArray = new double[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        pNewDoubleArray[i] = i * 3 + 2;
    }

    *pDoubleArray = pNewDoubleArray;
}

void main()
{
    double dbls[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    double* pArray = dbls;

    // this will change what pArray
    // points to
    someFunc(&pArray, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

As I've commented before, the latter approach will lead to memory leaks if `pArray` points to a heap allocated array before calling `someFunc`.