# What's the syntax for creating an array of pointers to another class?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

If I have a class with a private variable that's supposed to hold an array of pointers to another class, is the following syntax correct?

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        int arraySize;
        SomeOtherClass* classPtr[];
}
```

Later, when I want to dynamically allocate memory for this array in a function in MyClass that accepts an ifstream, reads from a file, and fills the array, would I do it like this?

```
void createArray(std::ifstream& fin)
{
    //the first int is the array size
    fin >> arraySize;
    string tempString; //the file is formatted string int string int etc.
    int tempInt;

    classPtr[arraySize];

    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        fin >> tempString;
        fin >> tempInt;
        //assume the constructor is defined
        classPtr[i] = new SomeOtherClass(tempString, tempInt);
    }
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to need an array, why do you want one?

Comment: The short answer is, because that's what the assignment calls for.  The classPtr is supposed to keep track of multiple instances of SomeOtherClass.

Comment: Nothing in there spells _array_ though...

Comment: You can never create a pointer *to a class*.

Comment: Maybe it's a poor assignment.  It states "Create another class that maintains a private array of SomeOtherClass instances."  "You will dynamically allocate the array to be of the exact size, then fill it by reading from the file."

Comment: You're right Ed.  I should have said "object" or "instance of a class."  thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212206/creating-array-of-pointers-to-class-object, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982633/c-pointer-arrays, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887615/creating-an-array-of-object-pointers-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498039/how-to-create-array-of-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's incorrect. You cannot yet use variable length arrays in C++

That should be

`SomeOtherClass** classPtr;`

And in `createArray()`

```
...
classPtr = new SomeOtherClass*[arraySize];
...
```

And yes, forget everything I said and use `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays must have a static size at compile time, but in your case you don't know the size until you read it from the stream at runtime.  For a dynamically sized array, you should use a `vector` instead:

```
std::vector<SomeOtherClass*> classPtr;
```

Then in your code below:

```
classPtr.reserve(arraySize);
.....
classPtr.push_back(new SomeOtherClass(...));
```

This being said, *using raw pointers in a vector is not advised* and should be done with care.  Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361227/507606) to learn more about it and whether its right for you.  More likely than not, you just want a `vector` of your objects:

```
std::vector<SomeOtherClass> vec;
.....
vec.push_back(SomeOtherClass(...));
```

When using a `vector` of objects you should be sure to think about the move/copy semantics of your object and make sure that its right for your use case.

Comment: Having a vector of objects would require thinking about moving/copying objects during push_back and also if the vector has to change capacity. A vector of unique_ptr might be better.

Comment: @beldaz The referenced link provides plenty of alternatives to a `vector` of pointers, so I didn't want to repeat that answer.  I will add a note to thinking about moving/copying though.